# How to resize tkinter canvas.create_window() to fill the frame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI with `tkinter`. I want to keep the contents of the GUI in the middle of the root window and if I resize or move the window, I want the contents to stay in the middle. I also want to have a scrollbar on the right side. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def makelabelframe(root, text, row, col):
    label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text=text)
    label_frame.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)
    return label_frame

def makelabel(root, text, row, col):
    lab = tk.Label(root, text=text)
    lab.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)
    return lab

def makecombobox(root, values, row, col):
    box = ttk.Combobox(root, values=values, state="readonly")
    box.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)
    box.set(values[0])
    return box

def makebutton(root, text, command, row, col):
    button = tk.Button(root, text=text, command=command)
    button.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)

def makeframe(root, row, col):
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)
    return frame

def makecanvas(root, row, col):
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
    canvas.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)
    return canvas

def makescrollbar(root, canv, row, col):
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canv.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)
    return scrollbar

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    w, h = 1000, 500
    root.geometry("{}x{}".format(w, h))

    mainframe = makeframe(root, 0, 0)
    mainframe.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
    canv = makecanvas(mainframe, 0, 0)
    sb = makescrollbar(mainframe, canv, 0, 1)
    canv.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    canv.bind_all("<Configure>", lambda e: canv.configure(scrollregion=canv.bbox("all")))
    canv.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda e: canv.yview_scroll(int(-1*(e.delta/120)), "units"))
    frame = makeframe(canv, 0, 0)
    win = canv.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="center")

    labelframe1 = makelabelframe(frame, "Labelframe 1", 0, 0)
    makelabel(labelframe1, "Button 1", 0, 0)
    button_func = lambda: print("Click")
    makebutton(labelframe1, "Click this", button_func, 0, 1)

    labelframe2 = makelabelframe(frame, "Labelframe 2", 1, 0)
    makelabel(labelframe2, "Select number", 0, 0)
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    makecombobox(labelframe2, nums, 1, 0)
    makelabel(labelframe2, "This text is so long that it forces widgets outside the window", 0, 1)
    ls1 = ["Option 1", "Option 2"]
    makecombobox(labelframe2, ls1, 1, 1)

    labelframe3 = makelabelframe(frame, "Labelframe 3", 2, 0)
    makelabel(labelframe3, "1", 0, 0)
    makelabel(labelframe3, "2", 0, 1)
    makelabel(labelframe3, "Button 2", 1, 0)
    makebutton(labelframe3, "Compare images", button_func, 1, 1)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

The scrollbar is working and the contents are in the middle, but the problem is that `canv.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="center")` creates a window that is very small and the contents don't fit inside it. If I comment out the `create_window` function, I can see the contents but then the scrollbar isn't working anymore.

I have tried many things, such as doing this without `mainframe.place()` function, but then the contents are in the upper left corner and nothing seems to work. I also tried to make a resize function:

```
def resize(e):
    canv.itemconfig(win, height=e.height, width=e.width)
canv.bind("<Configure>", resize)
```

But this does not help. I also tried to make the canvas bigger:

```
def makecanvas(root, row, col):
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=700, height=700)
    canvas.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=15, pady=10)
    return canvas
```

But this put the contents to some random place.

How could I fix this?

Comment: If you change 'win' `anchor` from 'center' to 'nw', the top/left contents become visible then you might try including a horizontal scrollbar to access everything else. That's about all I've got...

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `<Configure>` event on `frame` instead of `canv` and update the `scrollregion` of `canv` inside the callback.  If you want to see all the widgets in the horizontal direction, you can resize `canv` inside that callback as well:

```py
def main():
    ...
    # don't bind <Configure> on canv
    #canv.bind_all("<Configure>", lambda e: canv.configure(scrollregion=canv.bbox("all")))
    canv.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda e: canv.yview_scroll(int(-1*(e.delta/120)), "units"))
    frame = makeframe(canv, 0, 0)
    win = canv.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw") # changed to "nw"
    # update width and scrollregion options of the canvas whenever frame is resized
    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canv.configure(width=e.width, scrollregion=canv.bbox("all")))
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, this kind of works, the frame is in the middle as I want it to be but the frame height is small. I can make the whole frame visible by adding: ```frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canv.configure(width=e.width, height=e.height, scrollregion=canv.bbox("all")))```, but then the scrollbar isn't working anymore. What I want is that if I make the window smaller, I want to adjust the scrollbar with it. Currently, the scrollbar is completely disabled if I add ```height=e.height```.

Comment: @programer If you set the height of the canvas to the same as the internal frame, why do you expect the scrollbar be activated?  Also making the window smaller does not change the size of the canvas.

Comment: I mean that I want it to activate if I make the root window smaller by dragging it smaller with mouse from the border. Of course I could do, e.g., ```height=e.height*0.99``` to activate the scrollbar, but even then dragging the root window smaller does not adjust the scrollbar. So basically if I make the root window smaller, I want the scrollbar to adjust with it so that I can see all widgets I have created by scrolling the scrollbar.

Comment: As I already said, resizing the window does not resize the canvas.  So the scrollbar will not be activated.

Comment: Is there a way to resize the canvas with the window?

Comment: @programer It is better to create another question.